# Acer C720 and Not Responding Touchpad

Tags: touchpad, hardware, chromebook

I recently live booted Ubuntu 14.04 in seaBIOS on Acer C720 Chromebook. Everything worked well accept the touchpad it just stay's there unresponsive. I intalled Ubuntu using the keyboard on my laptop ,but still had the same problem I tried all the mouse settings and it is still unresponsive.

Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Acer C720P Touchpad and Touchscreen are not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/575457/acer-c720p-touchpad-and-touchscreen-are-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience. Trackpad works with Linux 3.18 and up. Ubuntu 15.04 comes with it (which is upgraded to 3.19).

You may want to upgrade, or find repositories with debian version of the Kernel and install it your current ubuntu

Comment: Use the Ubuntu [mainline kernels](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) (See [How to](http://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) ) to update Ubuntu for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, any Linux distribution installed on a chromebook, requires running a script to rebuild kernel. Refer to this page here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chromebook#Touchpad_and_Touchscreen_kernel_modules

Also here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2190187

Alternativelly, what I did was to get a wirelesss mouse ($15 at Walmart or something). Simple solution if you don't want to get dirty with kernel and stuff.

Comment: Would the modifications to the kernel be done in a terminal?

Comment: Yes, basically.

Comment: I've posted a much more concise and new-user-friendly answer here, which I would recommend anyone with this problem check out.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/565856/how-do-i-fix-my-touchpad-on-my-acer-720-chromebook